# How can I move the result of this query that is stored in a DB from a server to a table that is on a DB of another server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
declare @consulta int
declare @string nchar(20)


set @consulta=(Select TOP 1 [ID] From Lookup order by ID DESC)

set @string = 'Events_' + CAST(@consulta as varchar);

EXEC ('Select EventID, LocalEventTimestamp, DeviceGuid, CardholderGuid From '  +@string);
```

I made a simple ETL process using OLE DB SOURCE using sql comand and I get the following error:

> Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [1]]: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code:
>   0x80004005.An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL
>   Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description:
>   "Incorrect syntax near 'From'."Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source
>   [1]]: Unable to retrieve column information from the data source. Make sure your target table in the database is available.

Please, if you know of a solution please let me know as soon as possible thanks in advance

Comment: Based on the title only, your google search string is `sql server linked servers`.

Comment: Hope this link help you ☺️https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3f02786c-e578-4c15-86ec-fd0248f36074/unable-to-retrieve-column-information-from-the-data-source-make-sure-your-target-table-in-the?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to query a table that doesn't exist.

Comment: The table if it exists and I execute the query in the DB and it returns all the data